# Ruby - string[i] = string[i].ord error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ascii

When creating a Caesar's Cipher, how come

`string[i] = string[i].ord`

gives me an error message ("no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String"), but a variable fixes the issue, e.g.

`cipher = string[i].ord` ?

Answer (score 3):

These two lines are completely different in terms of meaning.

Consider your first one:

```
string[i] = string[i].ord
```

This means "assign this value to position `i` in my string" which String attempts to dutifully do except, uh oh, you've given a number instead of a string so it errors out. You can fix this:

```
string[i] = string[i].ord.to_s
```

The second example creates a variable and those are not subject to he same restrictions.

Remember that in general terms `x[i] = y` is a *method call* where `x = y` is a variable assignment.

I'm not sure what your initial line is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to make sense to replace a single letter with a bunch of numbers. If you want to break out your characters:

```
string.chars.to_a
```

You can also get the raw bytes which skips the `ord` step:

```
string.bytes.to_a
```

Comment: Ahhh crystal clear now. Thanks so much! Not understanding the logic behind that was really driving me nuts!

Comment: No problem. If you come from a language with automatic type conversion like Perl, PHP or JavaScript then Ruby's stubborn refusal to deal with something like this might seem irritating. `'1'` and `1` are not the same thing in Ruby. You'll often need to convert if you want values to be combined.

Comment: "`x = y` is a variable assignment presuming `x=` is not defined as a method." – No. It's a variable assignment. Period. Local variables are defined at parse time, methods are defined at runtime. There's no way for the parser to even know whether or not such a method exists at that point in the code.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I should have been more specific, and you're right. `a.x = y` is different from `x = y`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is:

   ```
   string[i] = string[i].ord
   ```

   you tries to assign value of `string[i].ord` that is an `Integer` into a string that is array of chars (in fact on-char strings), so since array of chars can't accept into its row any other than `String` you got the exception *"no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String"* meaning that interpreter can't convert a number to a string.
2. Here is:

   ```
   cipher = string[i].ord
   ```

   you are assigning a value to an other variable that has no such restrictions as in the prevoius case, so the assignment is apssed well.

**NOTE:** That the first example was valid for rubies version 1.8 and below, since getting and setting a char value from/to the string has type of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You mention "Caesar Cipher", so I assue that you want to "move" the character's codepoint by some value, e.g. 13. To get the codepoint, you can use [`String#ord`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-ord), just like in your example:

```
str = 'ABC'
str[0].ord #=> 65
```

You can add 13:

```
str[0].ord + 13 #=> 78
```

But you can't directly assign that value, because [`String#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) does not allow<sup>1</sup> a codepoint as its argument:

```
str[0] = 78 #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

You can however convert the codepoint back to a character<sup>2</sup> via [`Integer#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
78.chr #=> "N"
```

Or, in one line:

```
str[0] = (str[0].ord + 13).chr
str #=> "NBC"
```

Now the other two characters:

```
str[1] = (str[1].ord + 13).chr
str[2] = (str[2].ord + 13).chr

str => "NOP"
```

Note that this approach only work for characters A - M.

---

1. Or "not any more", that feature was removed in Ruby 1.9.
2. A one-character `String` actually, Ruby doesn't have a `Character` class.